# Can I use "go" in a while inside a transaction?

Tags: sql-server

I would like to change the IDs of some rows in one table and I am trying this:

```
begin tran
    WHILE @iteradorAccion < @FilasTotalesAcciones
    BEGIN
         --some code
         update MyTable 
         set MyField = @Fieldvalue + '_old'

         insert into MyTable(MyField) VALUES(@FieldValue)
    END
rollback
```

how I am a unique constraint that is not allowed two rows with the same value in MyField, first I try to rename the actual row and later I try to insert the new row.

The problem is that I get an error of unique constraint. I think that is because the update of the value is not still go to the database, so I an trying to use "go" between the update and the insert, but the code is not correct.

I can use the "go" inside a while loop? or I need first use a loop to rename and a second loop to insert the new rows?

Thank so much.

Comment: Why you are updating whole table in a loop? How you are breaking the loop?

Comment: `GO` is not a SQL statement or command - it's a **delimiter** used in SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: The problem I think is not insert. You are updating whole table in each iteration by @Fieldvalue + '_old'. Just add some where clause.

Comment: I'm not sure about my answer, but I think using `Commit` can helpful.

Comment: er... this code won't even run. If its pseudo code, please indicate so

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, why it won't run? It is a valid TSQL code.

Comment: because the variables have not been declared

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps you need to change

```
  update MyTable 
         set MyField = @Fieldvalue + '_old'
```

to

```
  update MyTable 
         set MyField = @Fieldvalue + '_old' 
         where MyField = @Fieldvalue
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `COMMIT()` :

> **COMMIT TRANSACTION (Transact-SQL)**
>   Marks the end of a successful implicit or explicit transaction. If `@@TRANCOUNT` is `1`, `COMMIT TRANSACTION` makes all data modifications performed since the start of
>    the transaction a permanent part of the database, frees the resources
>    held by the transaction, and decrements `@@TRANCOUNT` to `0`. If
>    `@@TRANCOUNT` is greater than `1`, `COMMIT TRANSACTION` decrements
>    `@@TRANCOUNT` only by `1` and the transaction stays active.

```
COMMIT { TRAN | TRANSACTION } [ transaction_name | @tran_name_variable ] ]
[ ; ]
```

**transaction_name**
Is ignored by the SQL Server Database Engine. transaction_name specifies a transaction name assigned by a previous BEGIN TRANSACTION. transaction_name must conform to the rules for identifiers, but cannot exceed 32 characters. transaction_name can be used as a readability aid by indicating to programmers which nested BEGIN TRANSACTION the COMMIT TRANSACTION is associated with.

**@ tran_name_variable**
Is the name of a user-defined variable containing a valid transaction name. The variable must be declared with a char, varchar, nchar, or nvarchar data type. If more than 32 characters are passed to the variable, only 32 characters will be used; the remaining characters are truncated.